# Centrally assigning DHCP "user class" to clients?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp

I'm using Windows Server 2003 along with MS's DHCP server.  We're making some changes in our environment that we'd like to phase in - these changes will require a different default route, perhaps different DNS servers.  All of our clients are Windows - 2000, XP, Vista.

We'd like to find a way to say "these machines will get THIS default route/DNS, and that set of machines will get another set."

The DHCP "User Class" feature would seem to be a way to handle this, but I can't find anything about how to centrally assign the "User Class" for a given machine centrally. Everything I've found refers to issuing an ipconfig command on a given machine to change the user class.  Is there a different way?

I suppose that I could arrange it that machines in particular group run a script which issues that command - but is it persistent across boots?  The script wouldn't be run until the machine has a DHCP address and connects to the domain, so would it work for the next boot/DHCP renewal?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way that doesn't use a script.

I believe the solution is to configure the script to run at startup. It is not persistent across boots so you'd have to run it every time at startup.

```
C:\>ipconfig /setclassid "Local Area Connection" MyNewClassId

Windows XP IP Configuration

    DHCP ClassId successfully modified for adapter"Local Area Connection"
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783756(WS.10).aspx

My sense is that a more robust way of handling the issue would be to use MAC address reservations.